# Conditional Highlight: color change cell only if multiple others filled in

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I have a shift sign-up sheet in which I would like the cells in column `A` to be highlighted only once there is a value (name) in the corresponding cells in columns `B:D`.

In this example, I would like cell `A1` to be highlighted as all shifts are assigned, but cell `A2` to not be highlighted as not all shifts are accounted for. I tried `=countif(B6:D6, "<>")`, but this highlighted column `A` even if only one cell was filled in.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Webapps. Please read [ask] and [About asking](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/asking). Also, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) if an answer addressed your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well -. ([Why vote?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**custom formula: `=NOT(COUNTBLANK(B2:D2))`**

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

The rule you need to apply to range `A1:A` is:

```
=AND(B1:B<>"", C1:C<>"", D1:D<>"")
```